# Selecting one feature among intersections using ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, intersection, select, arctoolbox

I have a model which check the location of objects and select those which have the same position on the map.

[image]

I need to have a selection of only one object in intersections but not to doi it manually. Do any tool in ArcToolbox or process in ModelBuilder can complete such a task?

[image]

For instance, here I have six point objects which have intersections. How to choose only three of them, which have to be moved?

Comment: What is the algorithm for deciding which three of your six points need to be moved?  Is it the odd-numbered ones, the even-numbered ones, or something else?

Comment: Delete identical?

Comment: @PolyGeo, here is like the model look.  http://i.stack.imgur.com/HQCcO.jpg  Those points are moved by the untility which makes changes in field EDGEPOS, which means the location of point in the beginning and on the end of a certain road. The beginning is "0", the end is "1". Here I have only zeros. So I want the intersected points attributes to be changed automatically. Then if utility see "1" in EDGEPOS, it automatically move points to the end of roads. The problem is also about the quantity of points, which could be much bigger.

Comment: @FelixIP no, it won't solve a problem, see my new comment above.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any additional details.  Taking the 2-minute [Tour] will help introduce the site protocols.

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to do this by Python but I think this is still achievable by ModelBuilder, as advised by @FelixIP. My suggestion is to

- create a copy of your Selection by Location output as interim,
- run Delete Identical twice on both, your processing layer and the
  copy    layer.

From your example, if you have 6 points selected, you will create a new feature class with these points by Copy Features tool. Following this, you will run Delete Identical on your selection layer, which will leave 3 points and then run Delete Identical once more on the copy, which will again yield 3 points. Finally you need to re-calculate EDGEPOS field as 1 for the **copy** feature class and merge them back into one feature class.

A bit tedious but I think it will work.